# PHP Post-Method prepare() returns False

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, slim

Here is the Problem, I want to create a Post-Method for my Webservice. I'm uing the Slim Framework with PHP7 and an SQLite3 Database. I have the following code implemented:

```
$app->post('/api/generalinformation', function ($request) {


   try {
       $db = new PDO("sqlite:D:/Schule/notfunk_app/IPNF.db") or die("Cannot open Database");

       $query = "insert into nlv_GeneralInformation (SystemID, InformationID, Title, Description, Importance) values (:SystemID, :InformationID, :Title, :Description, :Importance);";
       $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

       if($stmt === false){
          die("prepare() failed");
       }
       $SystemID = $request->getparsedBody()["SystemID"];
       $InformationID = $request->getparsedBody()["InformationID"];
       $Title = $request->getparsedBody()["Title"];
       $Description = $request->getparsedBody()["Description"];
       $Importance = $request->getparsedBody()["Importance"];

       $stmt->bindParam(":SystemID", $SystemID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->bindParam(":InformationID", $InformationID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->bindParam(":Title", $Title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(":Description", $Description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(":Importance", $Importance, PDO::PARAM_INT);

       $stmt->execute();

       $db = null;
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
});
```

But the prepare() funktion always returns me false. I've testet the query and it works.

Comment: Start with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: After creating the `$db` object, try this: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. This will make it throw exceptions so your error message will be echoed.

Comment: PS no need to bind parameters with PDO. Just pass them as an associative array to `execute()`.